# Передача метода в качестве аргумента функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется следующий код:

```
import random

def summ():
    return random.randint(1, 100) + random.randint(1, 100)

def foo(summ):
    value = summ
    print(value)
    new_value = summ
    print(new_value)

foo(summ())
```

Могу ли я в value и new_value получить различные значения? При текущей реализации метод `summ()` вызывается один раз и результат его работы записыватеся в оба значения (value & new_value) и в результате будут выведены одинаковые числа.

Как мне заставить метод `summ()` отработать дважды?

Comment: В этом примере вы передали число, а не метод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передавайте ссылку на функцию, а не результат её вызова

```
def foo(f):
    value = f()
    print(value)
    new_value = f()
    print(new_value)

foo(summ)
```

Comment: И тогда, вместо числа, на консоль будет выведена ссылка на эту функцию. А как заставить её отработать?

Comment: Вы внимательнее на мой код посмотрите.

Comment: Прошу прощения, спасибо)